# Cron Python script to do a task if shutdown

Tags: python, cron, raspberry-pi

I have a python script that runs on my Raspberry Pi on boot automatically using a cron job. It works great. However, In my script I have the following exception or KeyBoard interupt so that if I exit the python script then my LCD data gets cleared

```
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    display.lcd_clear()
```

However, if i was to send a reboot command or shutdown command to the Pi then the Pi reboots with the last message still stuck on the LCD meaning that it doesn't execute the keyboard interrupt part of the code. I'm assuming a reboot isn't classified as a Keyboard Interrupt.

Does anyone know how I can make the LCD clear on shutdown and reboot too?

Thanks

Comment: I believe you need to send a command to the lcd. You might try importing the os module and using the command: os.system('clear'), but a keyboard interrupt only executes if you are sending a SIGINT signal to the process using the keyboard command 'cntrl-c' to exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html) module and use it to [capture](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.signal) all termination-related Unix system signals with proper handling. Such as `signal.SIGINT` and `signal.SIGTERM`